# MySQL left join query doesn't return rows with null value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I'm trying to get the result I want by mysql left join, but I can't.

This is table A :

```
+------------+
|       date |
+------------+
| 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-04-02 |
| 2020-04-03 |
| 2020-04-04 |
+------------+
```

table B :

```
+------------+----------+---------+
|       date | place_id | visitor |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 2020-04-01 |        1 |      10 |
| 2020-04-02 |        1 |      12 |
| 2020-04-03 |        1 |       7 |
| 2020-04-02 |        2 |      11 |
| 2020-04-03 |        2 |      17 |
| 2020-04-04 |        2 |      21 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

table C :

```
+----------+-------+
| place_id | place |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     A |
|        2 |     B |
+----------+-------+
```

the result I want:

```
+------------+-------+---------+
|       date | place | visitor |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 2020-04-01 |     A |      10 |
| 2020-04-02 |     A |      12 |
| 2020-04-03 |     A |       7 |
| 2020-04-04 |     A |  (null) |
| 2020-04-01 |     B |  (null) |
| 2020-04-02 |     B |      11 |
| 2020-04-03 |     B |      17 |
| 2020-04-04 |     B |      21 |
+------------+-------+---------+
```

I expected the last table above as the result for the query I wrote (A left join B),
but it worked like a inner join query.

Comment: on Table B

For 2020-04-04, place A & visitor doesn't exist. 

If you want NULL only for visitor then Place column should be in Table A.

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran what if I also have table C? (just added to the post) would it be possible to get the result using all 3 tables?

Comment: Table C ID  column doesn't have any relation .. so it doesn't really help.

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran I edited table B, how about this time? still no relation?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Why shouldn't it act that way? It acts how it's defined to act. If you want your misconceptions cleared up you need to tell us what you expected and why, and give justification per the manual or other reference--so we can tell you where you are going wrong & so you can catch your mistake yourself before asking. Otherwise what do we do, rewrite the manual? And guess where you misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` `tablea` and `tablec` to generate all possible combinations, and then bring `tablec` with a `left join`:

```
select a.date, c.place, b.visitor
from tablea a
cross join tablec c
left join tableb b on b.place_id = c.place_id and b.date = a.date
order by a.date, c.place
```